# Best practices when adding sugars during the fermentation process

Tags: fermentation, sugar, best-practices

I'm looking to take on a challenge of brewing an ale that is going to range between 14%-16% ABV, and among the many different steps, the most interesting is the inclusion of Demerara sugar and cane sugar in 1oz amounts daily (alternating between the types each day for 5 days in both primary, after the fermentation slows, and secondary).  The fermentation will take place in a carboy with a blow off tube vice your typical plastic airlock to ensure that if the fermentation overflows into the air lock, that it won't blow the cap off.

What is considered best practice when adding sugar to the carboy every day.  Should I use a funnel, and remove the 1/2in. tubing off the airlock and funnel it into the beer, then swirl the carboy to mix it in, or can I just remove the cork entirely, drop the sugar in, and replace the cork, or is there another method that is considered best practice for including the sugar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually add water to the sugar (a pint per pound or so) and boil it for 10 minutes and then chill it to around current fermentation temperature before adding it to the fermenting beer.   Sanitize everything really well, pull the plug from the mouth of the carboy, drop a funnel into it and pour.   There's no need to shake it up or anything, because the yeast's activity will stir it very well.

I don't know if this is the "best" way, but it has worked well for me.